# Python - Deleting Lines of Code In JSON File

Tags: python, json

I would like to search and replace multiple lines of code a JSON file with nothing except the first one that will use the users input but I cant get it to work I would like to search a JSON file and find the code im looking for and remove it or replace it with nothing.

I want to delete everything like the stuff inside and the { and the closing }, tag in my JSON file.

Code:

```
screenshoturl = input("Screenshot URL 1: ")

# Search JSON file for the placeholders and replace them with nothing.
removescreenshotsplaceholders = {
  'Screenshot URL 1':screenshoturl,
  '''{
  "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
  "url": "Screenshot URL 2",
  "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 2"
  },''':'',
  '''{
  "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
  "url": "Screenshot URL 3",
  "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 3"
  },''':'',
  '''{
  "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
  "url": "Screenshot URL 4",
  "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 4"
  },''':'',
  '''{
  "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
  "url": "Screenshot URL 5",
  "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 5"
  }''':''
  }

  with open('path/to/json/file') as infile, open(/path/to/to/save/copy, 'w') as outfile:
      for removescreenshots in infile:
          for screenshot, removescreenshot in removescreenshotsplaceholders.items():
              removescreenshots = removescreenshots.replace(screenshot, removescreenshot)
          outfile.write(removescreenshots)
```

This is what I want the script to search for in the JSON file and remove it:

```
'''{
      "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
      "url": "Screenshot URL 2",
      "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 2"
      },''':'',
      '''{
      "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
      "url": "Screenshot URL 3",
      "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 3"
      },''':'',
      '''{
      "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
      "url": "Screenshot URL 4",
      "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 4"
      },''':'',
      '''{
      "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
      "url": "Screenshot URL 5",
      "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 5"
      }''':''
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "tabs": [
    {
      "tabname": "Details",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "Some Name",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": false,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "itemCornerRadius": 6,
          "itemSize": "",
          "screenshots": [
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 1",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 1"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 2",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 2"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 3",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 3"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 4",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 4"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 5",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 5"
            }
          ],
          "ipad": {
            "itemCornerRadius": 9,
            "itemSize": "{320, 550.8266666666667}",
            "screenshots": [
              {
                "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
                "url": " Screenshot URL?size=640",
                "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL"
              }
            ],
            "class": "DepictionScreenshotView"
          },
          "class": "DepictionScreenshotsView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": " Description",
          "useSpacing": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Known Issues",
          "class": "DepictionHeaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "None",
          "useSpacing": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Latest Version",
          "class": "DepictionHeaderView"
        },
        {
          "title": "1.0",
          "text": "Latest Version Number",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Released",
          "text": "3/10/19",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Price",
          "text": "Free",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Developer",
          "text": "TestDev",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Contact Support",
          "action": "",
          "class": "DepictionTableButtonView"
        },
        {
          "spacing": 16,
          "class": "DepictionSpacerView"
        },
        {
          "spacing": 20,
          "class": "DepictionSpacerView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    },
    {
      "tabname": "Changelog",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "1.0",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": true,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Initial Release",
          "useSpacing": false,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/10/2019</small>",
          "useRawFormat": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    }
  ],
  "class": "DepictionTabView"
}
```

I tried it with and without `'''` and tried messing with the in and out file and some other stuff nothing seems to work so any help will be welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: i tried it with and without `'''` and tried messing with the in and out file and some other stuff nothing seems to work.

Comment: If there is a comma or a left parenthesis at the end of the line, then you don't need to use triple quotes. Alternatively, you can use a join character at the end of the lines, and this is a `\\` character. This character, if at the end of the line in the Python code, means that the following line will be associated.

Comment: as a suggestion, instead of thinking of this as a json and string problem, you will probably have much better luck parsing the json, and working with the actual python dictionary, and then rewriting the dict to a json with the correct elements removed. Don't work with raw strings of json when you can parse it instead.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Python and I have no idea how to do that @Paritosh Singh but thanks.

Comment: @s3n0 im confused on how to do this can you possibly show me and example?

Comment: I do not quite understand it. What exactly do you need? Do you want to find and delete the contents of that mentioned data section? Exactly in the same format? If you want to insert triple quotes into a Python variable, you can use single or double (opposite) to hold triple quotes - for example: `test="""Hello '''World'''"""`. You can test this in Python console: `print(test)`.

Comment: I want to delete everything like the stuff inside and the `{` and the closing `},` tag in my JSON file.

Comment: OK, but it's best if you upload a file to the internet, how it looks exactly and what you want to remove from it .-). There are more ways how to do it... for example, the use of the `re` (regex) module, which requires some regex practice, unfortunately. Do you know the `json` module from Python? https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html It can transform JSON/Java syntax data <- from/to -> dictionary data type in Python. Maybe it could help with this `json` module.

Comment: Updated post @s3n0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little complicated. Your JSON file format contains many `<list>` data (according to Python interpretation). I wrote you a quick and simple solution - see the source code below. However, it would like to improve the code for the custom parser, or to improve the transformation from JSON to Python and vice versa. You could also truncate the OOP code into a single row like: `data = json.loads(open('/tmp/a.json','r').read())`. But you wrote that you are still new to Python. So on multiple lines it's better for understanding. Test over the Python console, otherwise you must paste all variables into `print()`.

```
import json

### read json data from file
#with open('/tmp/a.json') as f:
#    data = json.load(f)

### read text from file
with open('/tmp/a.json','r') as f:
    data = f.read()

### decode JSON data
data = json.loads(data)

print('- check before:')
data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

print('- Now we\'re going to overwrite the whole frame with "screenshots" for one, the first one that\'s already there. So there will only be the first record, i.e. "Screenshot URL 1" as you like.')
data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']  =  data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0] 

print('- check after:')
data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

### write encoded JSON data to output file
### warning - the tree structure will be deleted (all newlines), but the JSON format should remain original
with open('/tmp/b.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```