# Python - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

Whenever I run the code below, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

I am unsure how to fix this. I want to search the json file and find "Screenshot Package" and replace it with user input but I just get that error.

My code:

```
numberofscreenshots = input("How much screenshots do you want?: ")

if numberofscreenshots == "1":

    screenshoturl = input("Link to screenshot: ")

    with open('path/to/json/file','r') as f:
        data = f.read()

    data = json.loads(data)

    # Check the data before.
    print( data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'] )

    # Overwrite screenshots placeholders in template file if more then one.
    data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']  =  data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]

    # Check after to make sure it worked.
    print( data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'] )

    # Now search for the screenshot option and add users input.
    screenshotplaceholdertext = {"Screenshot URL 1":screenshoturl}
    for removescreenshotplaceholders in data:
        for screenshotplaceholder, removescreenshotplaceholder in screenshotplaceholdertext.items():
            removescreenshotplaceholders = removescreenshotplaceholders.replace(screenshotplaceholder, removescreenshotplaceholder)
        data.replace(removescreenshotplaceholders)

    # Write data to JSON file.
    with open('path/to/json/file', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
else:
    print("Something went wrong.")
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory to me. There's no `replace()` method on dictionaries. Also, even if it did have, it would probably take two arguments...

Comment: Your code makes no sense.. Why are you looping through a dict you made  that has only one key first of all, and we don't know what data looks like or what your indended results are.

Comment: @Jab: Those data are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090638/python-deleting-lines-of-code-in-json-file  The OP continues to solve the problems, but since the issue concerns another issue, it has now created a new topic and forgot to add the content of exemplary JSON data.

Comment: @Jim: The `.replace()` method cannot be used for a dictionary data type. Methods available for dictionary can be found eg. here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_dictionary.asp To update an existing dictionary key, just use the `.update()` method, as @Jab said in its code below. I quote him: `data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'].update({"Screenshot URL 1":screenshoturl})` or use assign operator: `data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'] = {"Screenshot URL 1":screenshoturl}` . Working with nested vocabulary is complicated. You have to be careful what and where to rewrite.

Comment: @Jim: But... I think... you still use a different JSON file format. The format of the dictionary variable (original) is as follows: `{u'url': u'Screenshot URL 1', u'fullSizeURL': u'Screenshot URL 1', u'accessibilityText': u'Screenshot'}`. The `'url'` key may not be retained?!

Comment: Its still the same just changed some stuff before posting lol my bad. @s3n0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to replace the value for key `"Screenshot URL"`  with `screeenshoturl`. If so you're going about it all wrong. Try this:

```
with open('path/to/json/file','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# Check the data before.
try:
    data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]
except ValueError:
    print("No Screenshots")

# Overwrite screenshots placeholders.
data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']  =  data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]

#from the error, I'm getting that data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']
#is now a dict, so there should only be one "Screenshot URL" key so no need
#to do any loops here, just replace the key.
data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'].update({"Screenshot URL":screenshoturl})

with open('path/to/json/file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I got it working after a few modifications to fit my code but now I want to add another row for more options like 'Screenshot URL 2' how would I go about doing this? Also if you want can you example to me more of how this code works?

Comment: If you don't know how this works then you're going to need to do some research on how dicts work. But if you want to update 2 keys in the dict just add another key/value pair in the update dict like so: `data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'].update({"Screenshot URL":screenshoturl, "Screenshot URL 2":screenshoturl2})`

Comment: After I updated that to fit my code it doesn't work it only adds the first one this is what it looks like now `data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'].update({"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl1,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl1, "accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl2,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl2})`

Comment: it only adds the first one but not the second one.

Comment: The first what? Screenshot?

Comment: Oh I just noticed. You removed the list of screenshots in place of a dict. So when you update the same key 2X it only keeps one of them. So don't overrite the list and use the list notation at the end. Or just use different keys to denote different screenshot info

Comment: I want it to add both but with `screenshoturl1` and `screenshoturl2` like: `"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl1,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl1,
"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl2,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl2`

Comment: I already told you how. It's not the optimal way but you could change that line to: `"accessibilityText_1": "Screenshot_1","url_1": screenshoturl1,"fullSizeURL_1": screenshoturl1, "accessibilityText_2": "Screenshot_2","url_1": screenshoturl2,"fullSizeURL_2": screenshoturl2`

Comment: This won't work in my situation it needs to have them both named the same just with `screenshoturl2` instead of `screenshoturl1` I seem to can't get this work and I don't know to much about Python im still learning it.

Comment: You need to use the provided list then. Like I said.

Comment: I am very confused on what to do I been trying to mess with it all day but can't get it to do what I want it to do so any help please?