# Python | Add 2 of The Same Keys In A Dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How would I go about adding 2 of the same keys just with `screenshoturl2` and `screenshoturl1` from a dict to a JSON file?

This is the code I have right now and it works but it just only adds the first `screenshoturl1` and not `screenshoturl2` and I have no idea on how to make it add it. See replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112118/python-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-replace#comment96969348_55112317) for more and maybe helpful info about my topic

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import json
import fileinput

def NumberofScreenshots():
    global numberofscreenshots
    while True:
        try:
            numberofscreenshots = input("Number of Screenshots?: ")
            if numberofscreenshots == '':
                print("Please enter how much screenshots to include.")
                continue
            elif numberofscreenshots.isalpha():
                print("Please enter a number not a string.")
                continue
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            break
def ScreenshotURL():
    global screenshoturl1, screenshoturl2
    if numberofscreenshots == "1":
        screenshoturl1 = input("Screenshot URL: ")
    elif numberofscreenshots == "2":
        screenshoturl1 = input("Screenshot URL: ")
        screenshoturl2 = input("Screenshot URL: ")
    else:
        pass
def NumberofScreenshots1():
    if numberofscreenshots == "1":
        with open('path/to/json/file','r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())

        data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]

        data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']  =  data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]

        data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'] = {"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl1,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl1}

        with open('path/to/json/file', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(data))
    else:
        print("Try again.")
def NumberofScreenshots2():
    global data
    if numberofscreenshots == "2":
        with open('path/to/json/file','r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())

        data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]
        print(data)

        data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'] = data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'][0]
        print(data)


        data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'].update({"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl1,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl1, "accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": screenshoturl2,"fullSizeURL": screenshoturl2})
        print(data)

        with open('path/to/json/file', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(data))
    else:
        print("Try again.")


print("Pick Template:")
print("1. Default")
template = input("Template Name/Number: ")

if (template == "1"):
    NumberofScreenshots()
    ScreenshotURL()

    NumberofScreenshots1()
    NumberofScreenshots2()

# Show the user a error if they enter a number for a template that can't be found.
else:
    print("The template you are looking for can not be found!")
```

We are looking at the function called `NumberofScreenshots2`

JSON File:

```
{
  "tabs": [
    {
      "tabname": "Details",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "Some Name",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": false,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "itemCornerRadius": 6,
          "itemSize": "",
          "screenshots": [
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 1",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 1"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 2",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 2"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 3",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 3"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 4",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 4"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 5",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 5"
            }
          ],
          "ipad": {
            "itemCornerRadius": 9,
            "itemSize": "{320, 550.8266666666667}",
            "screenshots": [
              {
                "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
                "url": " Screenshot URL?size=640",
                "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL"
              }
            ],
            "class": "DepictionScreenshotView"
          },
          "class": "DepictionScreenshotsView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": " Description",
          "useSpacing": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Known Issues",
          "class": "DepictionHeaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "None",
          "useSpacing": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Latest Version",
          "class": "DepictionHeaderView"
        },
        {
          "title": "1.0",
          "text": "Latest Version Number",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Released",
          "text": "3/10/19",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Price",
          "text": "Free",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Developer",
          "text": "TestDev",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Contact Support",
          "action": "",
          "class": "DepictionTableButtonView"
        },
        {
          "spacing": 16,
          "class": "DepictionSpacerView"
        },
        {
          "spacing": 20,
          "class": "DepictionSpacerView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    },
    {
      "tabname": "Changelog",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "1.0",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": true,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Initial Release",
          "useSpacing": false,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 3/10/2019</small>",
          "useRawFormat": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    }
  ],
  "class": "DepictionTabView"
}
```

I want it to remove everything in `screenshots` and re-add it with the user input that they enter in the `screenshoturl1` and `screenshoturl2` so it will delete everything like the placeholders in `screenshots` and only add 2 back with the url the user enters in `screenshoturl1` and `screenshoturl2` and help will be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, otherwise they wouldn't be **keys** would they?

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing, so I want to clarify: You can't add the same key to a dict more than once, because that makes it not a dict in python. If you need more than one value with the same key, you can use the single key, and a list as the values tied to that key

Comment: Sorry if the title is confusing I am very new to python and don't know to much about it thats why I posted my question here but I am sill confused on how to go about doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do here, it looks like you would like to update one or two of the URLs, one at a time.

What you could do is go over each screenshot item, one at a time, and either update it or stop. This is easier and also lets you update all of them if you want to. This also means we don't have to ask how many to do up front (we just stop when we don't get any more).

```
import json

# Load the data
file_name = 'path/to/json/file'
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

# Dig into the data to find the screenshots
screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

# Loop over each screen shot, updating each one
for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
    print("Screenshot", number)
    print('\tCurrent data:', screen_shot)

    new_url = input(
        "\tPlease enter new URL (leave empty and press return to stop): "
    ).strip()

    if new_url:
        # Updating the data here will also update the 'full_data' object
        # as we are just referencing a part of it, not making copies
        screen_shot.update({"url": new_url, "fullSizeURL": new_url})
    else:
        print("\tAll done!")
        break

# Remove all entries which we did not update
screen_shots = screen_shots[:number]

# Save the data
with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```

Something else you may want to look into is returning results from your functions instead of using global variables, as this can quickly get very confusing with bigger scripts.

Comment: Thanks so much this seems better then before but now how would I add two urls instead of just one so have both `new_url` and `new_url2`

Comment: Do you mean that when the script finishes, any screenshots which you did not update are removed? So for example, if you only put in 1 the remaining 4 would go?

Comment: That could work to but I want to add another input field for another url and add both the first `new_url` and `new_url2` to the json file.

Comment: I would like the `new_url` and `new_url2` to be separate in the json file so it would look like something like this `{"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": "new_url","fullSizeURL": "new_url"},` and `{"accessibilityText": "Screenshot","url": "new_url2","fullSizeURL": "new_url2"}`

Comment: I've updated the script above to snip out entries that you didn't update. This means there will be as many in the output as you want. This will support 2, but it will also support 3 or 1 etc. If that's not what you need then you would probably need to change it, or go into more detail about what you expect to see as output in various different scenarios. Good luck!

Comment: Almost ... maybe? also thanks for your help so far but maybe this info will be helpful my script has two input fields for the user like `screenshoturl1` and `screenshoturl2` and I want to take that input the user enters in those two fields and add it to the json file in place of the placeholders and remove the unused placeholders sorry if im not explaining it well it's hard to explain I guess lol.

Comment: I think that's what this does, with the exception that it will allow between 0 and 5 replacements. Give the script a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: It works but maybe im just confused because once I enter something in the input field and hit enter it only lets me enter 1 url how do I go about showing another input field after the user hits enter for another url.

Comment: You then enter another one and that gets added in the next slot, and another until you are done. I think maybe you need to take and adapt what has been provided here for your specific use case. The idea is to get you on the right track, not necessarily write the script for you.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood what I was asking or maybe you did and its just me lol but I am confused on how to let the user enter more then one url because when I enter a url in the `new_url` field and hit enter it doesn't show another input field I see it says `(press return to stop)` but I want it so when the user hits enter another input field comes up for another url. Sorry if I am annoying you I just don't understand how to do this.

Comment: It might not be the best wording but if you type a URL and press enter it continues. If you only press enter it will stop. So to enter two URLs: type a URL, press enter, type a URL, press enter, press enter.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me like that I tried to type a url with and without `http` or `https` also tried ending it with a `/` but nothing seems to work it still only adds the first url entered to the json file.

Comment: Does your source file have more than one entry? This works by using the source file as a template. If the input file has 1 screenshott, it will only output a maximum of 1 screenshot. If it has 100 it will work with up to 100. If you want to be able to output more than the input file, you will need to change the script.

Comment: I still get can't get it working maybe its something simple and I am just overlooking it I uploaded my script to google drive so you can take a look if you want. Thanks! Please tell me once you downloaded it because I don't want to keep it up for to long because its still in development and I don't want it public yet. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h9FSRVXBkOk3KsQedmihWDKxKrNn2-77. The code you provided is at line 190 and the input field is at line 141. Also once I get this working and ready for public use I will include your name above the code just to credit you for the help if you want.

Comment: Yep, kind of looks like I was suggesting. The source file only has one entry, which means you can only input one thing. If you want to let people add 1 or 2, then changing the default.json "tabs.views.screenshots" list to have 2 entries will do it (just copy the part again). The code I've provided will work for as many as you add. Although it's kind of a weird way to do it. You don't really need a template to do it at all. I'll update the answer to show you how... but it's Friday night sorry! I'd be curious to know what this is all about.

Comment: Umm... on second thoughts. There's a lot going on in that script. Even if you add to the template it won't work, as you've changed the code I've given you to only ask the question once, and then keep the answer. It needs to ask every time. You have to remove the "new_url = new_url" part which breaks the idea. Sorry...

Comment: What do you suggest I do then? I can't ask the question after the script runs it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Just noticed I might have included the wrong default.json file here is a updated version https://pastebin.com/Vwymjc6F

Comment: I'm not sure where you think the 'script' is in this context. You can ask things in a loop without it being outside of the 'script'. My general feeling is you might not have the problems you think you have. There is a sister site for general code review which might be more appropriate: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. On the whole I think stackoverflow is for finding answers to more specific issues.

Comment: Cool thanks but one more thing the script is no longer removing the non-updated placeholders you know why this is?

Comment: Nope sorry. The `screen_shots = screen_shots[:number]` is intended to do this. Maybe start looking there?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your value a collection (like a list or a tuple). For added convenience you can use defaultdict. So if you wanted to have two values for a key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

multiValueDict = defaultdict(list)

multiValueDict[1].append(1)
multiValueDict[1].append(2)
print(multiValueDict[1])
```

And this outputs:

```
[1, 2]
```