# Loop a Variable For Input Field Inside For Statement In Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to show the users another input field but it doesn't work unless I do this inside the For loop for `new_url` `new_url = input("Please enter new URL for a screenshot (press return to stop): ").strip()` but I want to move the input field to somewhere outside of the For loop so I tried doing this for the input field like `new_url = new_url_input` and take the `new_url_input` varable and add it somewhere else in my code like `new_url_input = input("Please enter new URL for a screenshot (press return to stop): ").strip()` but when I do this it only displays the code once but it should work like when the user presses enter it show another input field. Please see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169845/11204574) for more information about my topic.

Original Code:

```
# Load the data
file_name = file_name = path/to/json/file
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

# Dig into the data to find the screenshots
screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

# Loop over each screen shot, updating each one
for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
    new_url = input("Please enter new URL (press return to stop): ").strip()

    if new_url:
        screen_shot.update({"url": new_url, "fullSizeURL": new_url})
    else:
        break

# Remove all entries which we did not update
screen_shots = screen_shots[:number]

# Save the data
with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```

Example of how I want it to work/look:

```
new_url_input = input("Please enter new URL (press return to stop): ").strip()

# Load the data
file_name = path/to/json/file
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

# Dig into the data to find the screenshots
screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

# Loop over each screen shot, updating each one
for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
    new_url = new_url_input

    if new_url:
        screen_shot.update({"url": new_url, "fullSizeURL": new_url})
    else:
        break

 # Remove all entries which we did not update
 screen_shots = screen_shots[:number]

 # Save the data
 with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
     json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```

Comment: I dont know what you are exactly looking for. But based on dynamic new_url_input. You can use inline lambda method first line inside forloop. something like this... new_url = get_new_url_input()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `input()` it returns a string and in the loop you're just assigning that string to a new variable. You'll need to call `input()` again in some way, even if it's wrapping it in a function, for example using `lambda` as below...

```
new_url_input = lambda: input("Please enter new URL (press return to stop): ").strip()

# ...other code...

for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
    new_url = new_url_input()
```

---

EDIT: Now that I understand what you're saying (the instructions on the input prompt helped), I think this is what you're trying to do...

```
new_url_inputs = []
input_prompt = 'Please enter new URL (press return to stop): '
new_url_input = input(input_prompt).strip()
while new_url_input:
    new_url_inputs.append(new_url_input)
    new_url_input = input(input_prompt).strip()

# ...other code...

for number, screen_short in enumerate(screen_shots):
    new_url = new_url_inputs[number]
    # ...etc...
```

Comment: This wont work for me because I want to take the input first so even when doing this placing the `new_url_input` somewhere doesn't run until it gets to the For loop I want to ask the question get the input and use it later in/for the For loop .

Comment: @Unknown Check out my edit for something I think will help.

Comment: Thanks but when I run it I get this error `new_url = new_url_inputs[number]   IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Because you must have more screen shots than entered URLs, so catch the exception and deal with it however you want.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to deal with this yet still very new to Python.